# Deploy Raw Source Code from GitLab Repository

Tags: wordpress, continuous-integration, gitlab, rsync

I have a Gitlab repository containing a WordPress theme - php, js, and css files. My desired result is that when I push a change to the 'main' branch of the repo, the theme files are deployed, raw, without any build or test steps, to my remote server.

I have a .gitlab-ci.yml file set up with 'deploy' as its only step.

The script triggers on 'only: -main' and successfully accesses my remote server via ssh.

What I'm unsure of is how to send the entire raw repository to the remote.

Here is the 'script' portion of my yml:

```
- rsync -rav --delete project-name/ /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/project-name/ username@my.ip.add.ress:public_html/wp-site/wp-content/themes/
```

When the pipeline runs, I receive the following two errors:

```
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/builds/username/project-name/project-name" failed: No such file or directory (2)

rsync: [sender] change_dir "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/project-name" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Is GitLab looking in /builds/ its default behavior? I am not instructing it to do so in my yml.

Is there some other file path I should be using to access the working tree for 'main' in my repository?

Comment: What's your source and what's your destination directory? What's `project-name/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I misunderstood the rsync syntax. I thought the --delete flag included a parameter thereafter, meaning 'delete any existing files in the following directory' rather than what it actually does, which is to auto-choose the destination directory. Once I removed 'project-name/' and corrected the GitLab (origin) file path to '/builds/username/project-name/' the deployment occurs as intended.